# I can't create react app using npx command

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cmd, create-react-app, npx

Whenever I type this command:

```
npx create-react-app project-app
```

It doesn't work, [and outputs this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRBXf.png).

I tried reinstalling `nodejs`, creating the react app in another folder, checking the latest version of `create-react-app`. All of which output the same error message.

Comment: Consider adding the error message text -- as text -- to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for more on this. You will increase the probability of others responding to your question if you invest the time to follow the stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that npm is not able to find the specified file. Check the pathname and make sure that it is in the correct location. You can also try running `npm cache clean --force` to clear the npm cache. For more information, see this npm page.

Answer (score 0):

use `npm install --verbose` verbose mode or `npm install --loglevel=verbose`  debug mode to see where the npm is going to find the file path and accordingly set the path.